# Access Office 365 Online Archive via EWS

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I'm using Exchange Web Services to sync data from an office 365 account. The account owner is reporting that we're missing data, specifically that has been archived. We go through the standard EWS sync folders/items process to sync an entire account - is it possible that office 365 online archive is not included in that sync? When the user moved some of the emails from archive to a random new folder, we synced them (they showed up as new items).

The odd part - not having any issues with other users from the same office 365 organization.

Comment: You need to show the code your using but you would have to explicitly include the online archive which is physically another mailbox.

Comment: I'm going through the whole flow described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-synchronize-folders-by-using-ews-in-exchange - so the online archive is not included in the SyncFolderHierarchy call? @GlenScales

Comment: No your only making the request to the Primary Mailbox, you need to treat the Online Archive as a separate Mailbox with a Separate Hierarchy (also separate dumpster etc). Also don't confuse the new Archive folder which is just a folder in the Primary Mailbox with the Online Archive two different thing entirely

Comment: Ok thanks @GlenScales - a little confused on how to get the folder hierarchy for the online archive. Can't relevant find documentation, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Its no different to the primary mailbox just use  WellKnownFolderName.ArchiveMsgFolderRoot

Comment: Thanks @GlenScales , there is still some data we can't seem to find that a customer is reporting exists in their archive. Is there a support channel we can go through with a specific customer case that you know of?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ArchiveMsgFolderRoot` as the WellKnownFolder.

The full list of options can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername?view=exchange-ews-api